# Anki Cards: Batch import audio media

Tags: audio, batch, anki

I have a spreadsheet of over 5,000 cards that I want to import into Anki.

On each row, there is a reference to an audio file.

Is there anyway to batch import the audio files?

I know after the cards have been imported, I can click on the attachment symbol and then select the audio file. But doing that for over 5,000 cards will take forever! Any method to automate the process would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I did it:

1. In my Spreadsheet, the audio files were in column F2.

So in a new column (F3) I added the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("[sound:#]", "#", F2)
```

So the final output was like this:

```
[sound:vocab13en.mp3]
```

2. In Anki, I went to my user folder. On a mac this is in `USERNAME/ANKI/User1`.
   In there, there is a folder called "Collection.media"
   Pop all your audio files in that folder (It's worth renaming them with a prefix, so they don't get mixed up as you can't use separate folders. If you do this, rename them in the spreadsheet).
3. Open Anki and create a new Deck. Create a new card and make sure it has fields for Audio. Click on the "Cards..." button and add the audio field to your template.
4. Finally, import your spreadsheet making sure the audio column (created in column F3 in step 1) is mapped to your audio field (created in step 3).

Voila! Now all your Anki cards will be imported with audio files.